# Efficiently implementing Birman-Schiper-Stephenson(BSS) protocol's delay queue

Tags: data-structures, queue, distributed-computing

I am using the [Birman-Schiper-Stephenson](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~gcao/teach/513/read/vsynch2.pdf) protocol of distributed system with the current assumption that peer set of any node doesn't change. As the protocol dictates, the messages which have come out of causal order to a node have to be put in a 'delay queue'. My problem is with the organisation of the delay queue where we must implement some kind of order with the messages. After deciding the order we will have to make a 'Wake-Up' protocol which would efficiently search the queue after the current timestamp is modified to find out if one of the delayed messages can be 'woken-up' and accepted.

I was thinking of segregating the delayed messages into bins based on the points of difference of their vector-timestamps with the timestamp of this node. But the number of bins can be very large and maintaining them won't be efficient.

Please suggest some designs for such a queue(s).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the delay -- didn't see your question until now.  Anyhow, if you look at Isis2.codeplex.com you'll see that in Isis2, I have a causalsend implementation that employs the same vector timestamp scheme we described in the BSS paper.  What I do is to keep my messages in a partial order, sorted by VT, and then when a delivery occurs I can look at the delayed queue and deliver off the front of the queue until I find something that isn't deliverable.  Everything behind it will be undeliverable too.

But in fact there is a deeper insight here: you actually never want to allow the queue of delayed messages to get very long.  If the queue gets longer than a few messages (say, 50 or 100) you run into the problem that the guy with the queue could be holding quite a few bytes of data and may start paging or otherwise running slowly.  So it becomes a self-perpetuating cycle in which because he has a queue, he is very likely to be dropping messages and hence enqueuing more and more.  Plus in any case from his point of view, the urgent thing is to recover that missed message that caused the others to be out of order.

What this adds up to is that you need a flow control scheme in which the amount of pending asynchronous stuff is kept small.  But once you know the queue is small, searching every single element won't be very costly!  So this deeper perspective says flow control is needed no matter what, and then because of flow control (if you have a flow control scheme that works) the queue is small, and because the queue is small, the search won't be costly!